# Automating Access Queries and Report Generation

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I have an access database which consists of employee records. I am trying to generate a report for each record separately (as a PDF with the file name as the Employee Name). In addition to this I have a query that needs to be run per record to generate some external metrics. Kindly advise me on how to proceed as I currently unable to produce anything significant.
Thanks in advance,
Vibhor

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a moment to post a little more about what you have tried so far, your input data, and what your desired output is

Answer (score 0):

- Create a report for the single employee.
- Select the specific printer you want in the report (Page Setup). I set AdobePDF to print in pdf.
- Save the report.
- When you open the report for a given employee you have apply a filter to see only the selected one.
- Set the report caption with employee name, id, etc. It will be used as filename when saving in pdf

  DoCmd.SetWarnings False                         *' Disable warnings*
  DoCmd.OpenReport ***YourReportName***, acViewDesign, , ***YourFilterCondition***    *' Open report*
  Reports!rptQuotDetails.Report.Caption = ***YourEmployeeNameAndID***
  DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll                       *' print report*
  DoCmd.Close acReport, ***YourReportName***, acSaveNo            *' Close report w/o saving*
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True  Close                       *' Re-enable warnings*

You can use this snippet as the code for _Click event of a button.

Alternatively you can use the employee ID or its name o whatever within report code to set the caption (Me.caption = ...).